# Restore Purchase in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to add a restore button to my app, I have a non-consumable inApp purchase and the purchase part works fine. I have a button that calls this two methods:

```
product_id = "RemoveAdsIAP";
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
```

and this the purchasing code:

```
func buyConsumable(){
    succssessIAP = false
    if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
        var productID:NSSet = NSSet(object: self.product_id!);
        var productsRequest:SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID);
        productsRequest.delegate = self;
        productsRequest.start();
    } else {
        displayErrorAlert()
    }
}

func buyProduct(product: SKProduct){
    var payment = SKPayment(product: product)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment);
}

func productsRequest (request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {
    var count : Int = response.products.count
    if (count>0) {
        var validProducts = response.products
        var validProduct: SKProduct = response.products[0] as SKProduct
        if (validProduct.productIdentifier == self.product_id) {
            buyProduct(validProduct);
        } else { }
    } else {
        displayErrorAlert()
    }
}

func request(request: SKRequest!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    activityIndicatorShop.stopAnimating()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
    displayErrorAlert()
}

func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
    succssessIAP = false
    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        if let trans:SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction{
            switch trans.transactionState {
            case .Purchased, .Restored:
                if (product_id == "GetNextFactIAP" && succssessIAP == false) {
                    startController.getData()
                    startController.hideContainerView()
                    succssessIAP = true
                }
                if (product_id == "RemoveAdsIAP" && succssessIAP == false) {
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "viewAdsBool")
                    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
                    startController.removeOnce()
                    disableAds(true)
                    succssessIAP = true
                }
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
                break;
            case .Failed:
                SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction as SKPaymentTransaction)
                activityIndicatorShop.stopAnimating()
                displayErrorAlert()
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I press the button nothing happens, I've added a log statement to check if the updatedTransactions method was called and it wasn't, What's the problem?

Comment: Your question needs to be more specific. Which code is called, and which isn't? The button code?  The updatedTransactions method? etc. Is the delegate set? Do you implement the failure methods? Are those called? If so what errors are passed in?

Comment: the updatedTransactions is not called, I will add the full code since I don't know what's missing.

Answer (score 0):

Your products_id has the wrong format.
It should be more like

```
product_id = "com.xxxxxxxxx.RemoveAdsIAP"
```